# Entity is inserting when I want it to attach

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, poco

I have the two classes:

```
public class PartDefinition
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual Module Module { get; set; }
}

public class Module
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then I try to perform this action:

```
PartDefinition part = new PartDefinition(partNumber, module);
context.PartDefinitions.Add(part);
context.SaveChanges();
```

The module that I am passing to the new part definition already exists in the database. However, when I save the new part definition instead of adding the current module as a foreign key it inserts a completely new module.

How can I change this?

Comment: Regarding your code sample, you've listed the creation of a `PartDefinition` using a constructor but have not defined it earlier on, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not have any [Key] attributes representing the primary keys in the database; it adds a new module every time. Try marking Id property with [Key] attribute.
Also try to use the same context instance while fetching module and inserting part.

Comment: I've tried that but the outcome is still the same. Besides I've understood that naming the var Id tells EF that this is the Primary Key Id.

Comment: @RickEyre are using the same context for fetching the module and saving new part?

Comment: No I am not. Should they be the same?

Comment: Okay so I switched to using the same context and it works now. Is there a way that I can use two different contexts and still get the same behaviour?

Comment: @RickEyre In order to use two different contexts, you need to attach module item to context before adding part. And another 0 score answer as well:)

Comment: I'm unable to put a score. I don't have enough reputation :(.

Comment: @RickEyre glad to help anyway:)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your Module object's Id is set to a value?  If it is zero, then Entity Framework will see it as a new relationship.

Comment: Consider adding an ID value in the PartDefinition as well.

    `public int ModuleId { get; set; }
     public virtual Module Module {get;set;}`